# Navigate to UIViewController in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to navigate to a `UIViewController` using Swift 2.3. To be more precise, I am trying to reload the `UIViewController` that is currently active. I do not know which view the user currently has active, so this must be defined dynamically.

I have tried several approaches, but they all result in either compile or runtime errors.

Is something like this possible?

```
let activeViewIdentifier = ??? // Get currently active view identifier as a string
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(activeViewIdentifier, sender:self)
```

Comment: for refresh purpose you can call viewwillapear and viewdidload methods

Comment: You shouldn't call those methods yourself as it may invoke calls to the superclass methods which would be unexpected. You can, however, create your own methods which are called from viewDidLoad etc and while you also call directly when you need to refresh the view

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this :

Objective-C :

```
self.navigationController.topViewController.restorationIdentifier
```

Swift :

```
self.navigationController?.topViewController?.restorationIdentifier
```

Comment: When accessed from a function within my `BaseUIViewController` class (inherits from `UIViewController`), `self.navigationController?.topViewController?.restorationIde‌​ntifier` is nil - is that expected?

Comment: Yes expected for some reasons. Possibly your view controller not capsulated by a navigationConroller. You can open your storyboard and find your initial viewController (arrow at left) and select it, and after from menu "Editor>Embed In> Navigation Controller" to make this possible.

Comment: I have a custom `UINavigationController`, which has a link to the initial `ViewController` in storyboard.

Comment: where you're calling self.navigationController?.topViewController?.restorationIde‌​‌​ntifier in app lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issues with your architecture; it's not the best approach to reload just everything on some View Controller you can chose;

Much better way of thinking is to determine, what exactly you want to reload and add methods to reload only thus things

Anyway, if my answer hasn't assure you, consider replacing existing view controller with new and presenting it with some animation, or without it; so your general algorithm may look like this:

1. Get new VC from storyboard, or creating new instance, if you don't prefer to use it
2. Push it over your existing controller
3. Reload stack of navigation controller, in which you are now

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I really want to reload the entire `ViewController`, but please correct me if I am wrong. I am doing it at a time where I have determined that internet connectivity has been lost, and possibly has returned. I am checking for connectivity in `viewWillAppear()`, so reloading the entire view seemed like the thing to do...

Comment: why entire view? :) may be you want to reload all your labels, I don't know, all tableViews? you can add method 'reload' and call it for the existed VC

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
let activeViewIdentifier = self.navigationController?.childViewControllers[(self.navigationController?.childViewControllers.count)!-1]
```

**You can use the restorationIdentifier, it's right above the Storyboard identifier and it's a UIViewController property.**

```
let activityIdentifierStr = activeViewIdentifier?.restorationIdentifier

self.performSegueWithIdentifier(activityIdentifierStr!, sender:self)
```

Comment: Runtime error: unsafe pointer. `activeViewIdentifier?.restorationIdentifier` is nil when accessed during `viewWillAppear()`